# PHP JQuery pin point on map based on address fetch from database

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I want to pin point a location in google maps based on the address grab from database, currently I have below script to show user's current geolocation but instead of based on their input which is saved in the db.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&extension=.js&output=embed"></script>

// Enable the visual refresh
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;

var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
    // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);

      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
  }
}

function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
  if (errorFlag) {
    var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
  } else {
    var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
  }

  var options = {
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
    content: content
  };

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
  map.setCenter(options.position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Is there anything I can work on above scripts to accomplish like what I want?

Answer (score 0):

That code is simply trying to check the actual location of the user and then to center the map into that position, thus its not doing what your question is asking for.

So to check the position determing from address, you would instead need to check [Geocoding APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)